# Error bounds for Trapezoidal Integral Approximation

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral approximation $T_{20}$ of $\int_0^52e^{-x/4}dx$.

Find the error bound for $T_{20}$ without calculating $T_N$ using the result that

Error($T_N$)$\le$${M(b-a)^3}/{12N^2}$

where  is the least upper bound for all absolute values of the second derivatives of the function $2e^{-x/4}$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

I got M=0.125 and a final answer of 0.0006510416667 but it is coming up as wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using

$$f(x) = 2e^{-\frac{x}{4}} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

I got

$$f''(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{4}}}{8} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $e^{-\frac{x}{4}}$ is a strictly decreasing function for $x \ge 0$, the maximum for $x \in [0,5]$ occurs at $x = 0$. From this, I also got $M = \frac{1}{8} = 0.125$, as you did.

Using your formula, I then got for the maximum error bound, using $b = 5$, $a = 0$ and $N = 20$,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{M(b-a)^3}{12N^2} & = \frac{5^3}{8(12)(20)^2} \\
& = \frac{125}{38400} \\
& \approx 0.0032552
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

You haven't shown your calculations, but I guess you have a mistake there somewhere. Since your value is almost exactly just $\frac{1}{5}$ of what I got, I suspect you used $(b - a)^2 = 5^2$ instead of $(b - a)^3 = 5^3$.